# Html.BeginForm() in Razor Form ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

The issue is that the form submission event is triggered but the relevant action isn't being called. Do I have to mention the action name in the submit event of the form or will it figure it automatically?

Below you can see the code.

I am making a form like this

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Meals per day" id="numOfMealsPerDay" value="@Model.numberOfMeals" />
               <input type="hidden" name="myHiddenInput" id="myHiddenInput" value="@Model.Id" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <button type="submit" class="button small" id="updateNumOfMeals">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

In my Jquery I am doing this

```
$('form').submit(function () {

    var numOfMealsPerDay = $('#numOfMealsPerDay').val();

    console.log("form submitted");

    if (numOfMealsPerDay != '' && numOfMealsPerDay > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('cannot be empty or less than 0');
    }


    return false;
});
```

In the controller I am doing like this

```
   [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult UpdateSettings()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("1");
        return Content("Thanks", "text/html");
    }
```

Comment: Why use both `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` attribute for the same action method?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it doesn't even go to my controller action. I am trying to Debug it, the code never reached there.

Comment: Where UpdateSettings() with proper parameters is? I'm not sure routing will pick parameterless method as last choice.

Comment: Can you check and post what's being sent to server. You can check in browser network panel or best option is to use Fiddler.

Comment: @SBirthare when I console logged **this.action** I got the URL to another action in the controller. Now I have specify the action and controller name in Html.BeginForm(...) and now it work.

Comment: Yeah as per convention it default to the current view name. On submit if you want to call another action, you will have to specify view name.

Comment: this thing is working but now I am getting **confirm form re-submission** dialog popping up. Is there a link somewhere?

Comment: @mohsinali1317: The browser will ask you to confirm the form repost if the current page is a result of a POST request, and you are trying to refresh the page.

Comment: @Guffa so what should be done in that case? What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: @mohsinali1317: You can avoid having the page being a result of a POST request by returning a `Redirect` from the action method that handles the POST request. Then the browser will do a GET request for the URL that you specify in the redirect.

Comment: @Guffa any example on how to do that?

Comment: @mohsinali1317: The concept is called [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (easier to search for when you know that) and there are [a lot of examples out there](https://www.google.se/search?q=asp.net+mvc+post+redirect+get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action name is specified by the route that is handling the request. If you haven't specified any routes you will be using the default route that catches an url in the form `/Controller/Action`.

As you don't specify any action and controller in the `BeginForm` method, it will use the same action and controller as the current page. You can use View Source in the browser to check that the generated `form` tag has the correct URL in the `action` attribute.

If the page is for example `/Meals/UpdateSettings` then the `form` tags `action` attribute will be the same, so the page will be posted back to the same address but with the POST http method instead of GET.

For that URL the `UpdateSettings` action in the `MealsController` controller would be used.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to mention the action name in the submit event of the form
>   or will it figure it automatically?

You don't have to specify it if the `HttpPost` action name is the same as the `HttpGet` one. If you have a different action name you have to specify it like this:

```
Html.BeginForm(string ActionName, string ControllerName)
```

You also have other 13 definitions than you can use if you need to specify additional details (route values, method, html attributes, etc...)